# Gatsby JS Build with broken links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Hi Guys so im new to this whole gatsby JS. Loving it so far. I have loaded some images through webpack and some external javascript via gatsby helmet. Everything works perfectly on development.

But when I take build the images and the scripts are all broken. Console says its a 404.

```
This is how I'm importing-  import heroImg from "../images/tiger.svg"

And this is how I call -  <img src={heroImg} alt="logo" className="img-responsive" />
```

Similarly for JS `<script src={withPrefix('../static/gsap.js')} type="text/javascript" />`

Everything is broken in build. but working in development.

One thing I found in the build is when i remove the "../" in the url in the developer console the images are showing up. So i assume its some path issue while taking build. How do i solve this? Please help

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this by adding path prefix in gatsby.